# the implementation of the arraylists

Tags: arrays, loops, kotlin, arraylist

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

    var arraylist= ArrayList<String>()
    arraylist.add("jena")
    arraylist.add("Laya")
    arraylist.add("Hussein")
    arraylist.add("Ahmed")

    println("First name:"+ arraylist.get(0))
    arraylist.set(0," Laya Hussein")

    println(" all element by object")
    for ( item in arraylist){
        println(item)
    }

    println(" all element by index")
    for( index in 0..arraylist.size-1){
       println(arraylist.get(index))
    }
}
```

My question why we add -1 for iterating?
it is not clicking with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices of the array are zero based. This means that in `arrayOf("A", "B", "C")`

*A* has index 0, *B* has index 1 and *C* has index 2. So the last valid index is the array's size - 1 which is `3 - 1 = 2`

If you don't want to worry about that you can use `indices` extension property which is an `IntRange` of all valid indices.

```
for(index in arraylist.indices) {
   println(arraylist[index])
}
```

Notice the replacment of `get` with the operator notation `[]` which makes the code more concise.

If you don't care for the index, avoid the headache alltogether and use forEach

```
arraylist.forEach {
   println(it)
}
```

Comment: Thank for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you don't add the -1, it will iterate through 0 to the size of the list. Which means, if we have a list of size 5, it will iterate:
`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

And obviously index 5 is not a valid index here, so we need to make sure we don't iterate too far.

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**Arrays in Kotlin have **zero-based** index. To iterate through the whole array we need to use indexes from **0** to **array.size()-1**. Operator `..` means including both ranges, so to iterate through the whole array:

```
for (index in 0..arraylist.size - 1) {
   // ...
}
```

We can use function `until` to avoid using `arraylist.size-1`, it includes left range but excludes right range:

```
for (index in 0 until arraylist.size) {
   // ...
}
```

Also we can use shorter version of **for** loop just to iterate through the all elements of array:

```
for (item in arraylist) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This is the more idiomatic solution.

Comment: Additionally there is `for(index in array.indices)`, `array.forEach` and `array.forEachIndexed`